# How to create Dynamic Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, session-variables, dynamic-arrays

What would be the best way to create a dynamic array for a user to add products to a basket then store them in a session variable, I have been told serilizable arrays would work however when looking online for a solution I came accross an `ArrayList` which seemed perfect but I can't seem to implement it.

I have a separate class called `Basket` with:

```
ArrayList basketItems = new ArrayList();
```

I need to be able to select a product from a gridview using the select link or alternatively using a listview and using my own button to then add the `bookID` to the array, which will then be stored in a session variable and sent to a basket page where the `bookID` will be used again against a SQL table to output the details of the book etc.

Comment: You should accept an answer by clicking the checkmark if the answer is want you are looking for. It will help the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we were in 2003 then yes, [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) could have worked fine but now I would recommend you using a generic [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) which will be type safe and you don't need casting.

So you could have the following collection:

```
List<int> productIds = new List<int>();
productIds.Add(1);
productIds.Add(2);
```

Answer (score 4):

The ArrayList is the usual .NET 1.x solution for this problem. If you are using .NET 2.0 or later, use a simple generic list (`List<T>`).

Like this:

```
var myIDs = new List<int>();
```

You can add items with the Add method.

```
myIDs.Add(2);
myIDs.Add(42);
```

You can assign it to a session variable this way:

```
Session["IdList"] = myIDs;
```

And you can recover it:

```
var stuff = (List<int>)Session["IdList"];
```

Hope this helps